# accept tcp [::]: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s

Tags: go

We have an API running on golang, this gets quite high traffic, all of sudden we got the following error today

> http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:8443: accept4: too many open
>   files; retrying in 1s

Couple of things I checked before is, max FD size, this is at decent size of 16k per process, but for some reason it reached max without providing much details.

Are there any gotools or tips to check how I can find what can cause this issue?

Comment: You might have hit the system limit of open file descriptors.

Comment: when i check other instances, they are not even at 1%, definitely something wrong, it shouldn't hit max

Comment: At 1% of what? Used file descriptors? Apparently, on that instance, the file descriptors are used up, which tells a lot about the traffic you receive and (assuming the other instances serving the same API) your load balancing. I often saw that behavior in cases where instead of using a connection pool to connect to a database backend, new connections were created for every request - and/or not closed, too.

Comment: only one box had the issue

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if Go tools exist to help with problems like this. There is problably some connection leak in the code.

A common leak that can happen is forgetting to call `resp.Body.Close()` after having consumed the payload of `http.Response`.

Idle connections could be another possible cause. According to HTTP package doc:

> By default, Transport caches connections for future re-use. This may leave many open connections when accessing many hosts. This behavior can be managed using Transport's CloseIdleConnections method and the MaxIdleConnsPerHost and DisableKeepAlives fields.

If that's the case, you could try to call explicitely `CloseIdleConnections` on your `Transport` handle, or to reduce `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` value.

Comment: This is on the receiver side, so client calls the server, the server is go api which had this issue, it doesn't have any outbound http calls

Comment: Depending on how you implemented your server, you could have the `resp.Body.Close()` leak. For server side application, you might want to check if timeouts are properly set. Here is an interesting  [reading](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/).